# Max length of the continuation token in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In my service that connects to Azure Cosmos DB I have some issue. The reason of it can be the length of the `continuationToken` that sometimes becomes big and it causes the system to cut it and to fail.

Does someone know what is the maximum possible length of `continuationToken`? This info can help to test this supposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In this response from Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/61#issuecomment-282663954) they say the following:

> - For the query continuation token, it’s length could go up to 16KB. The query engine utilizes the token to serialize its state so that it could resume execution correctly. Along with the resume state, the query engine would also serialize some of the index lookup work on the continuation token to avoid repeating the same work for each continuation.
>     If this is really a blocking issue for you, then I could give you some hints on trimming the continuation token before sending it back. By all means we do not recommend this unless this is an absolute must and is meant to be a temporary solution.
>     From our side, we’re considering allowing the user to specify maximum continuation token length, with the caveat that if serializing the resume state did not fit in the specified max size, the query execution will fail with an error. We don’t have a timeline for this work yet though.
> - For the short term, you could trim the token by removing #FPC. Please keep in mind that in some cases you might get #FPP (i.e. either #FPC or #FPP).
>     We’ll sure prioritize this work item and hopefully we could get around to it soon. 
>     Best Regards,

By the sounds of it the token can get quite big but it will still be accepted. However you have to keep in mind that transferring a token back end forth which is bigger than the document you get back might be a performance concern.

Answer (score 0):

With the updates in Azure Cosmos DB, you can now restrict the size of the continuation token if you are using the .Net SDK as documented here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.responsecontinuationtokenlimitinkb?view=azure-dotnet